# Strange uncatchable System.NullReferenceException in DeactivateMdiChild

Tags: c#, winforms, unhandled-exception

It is about C#/.NET Windows.Forms application.

I faced some weird behaviour of .NET - there is strange System.NullReferenceException exception inside .NET code and it is not possible to catch and handle such exception.

Here are exception details:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.DeactivateMdiChild()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmMdiActivate(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DefMDIChildProc(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

I tried to run my app with .NET 2.0 and with .NET 4.0 CLRs - it works the same way, it throws unhandled exception which is not possible to catch.

I tried to debug it with VS2012 and VS2019 - exception reported at the same location and it is impossible to catch or figure out a reason of exception.

When running *release build* of my app it reports unhandled exception here:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.DeactivateMdiChild()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmMdiActivate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Here is a method which leads to that exception:

```
/// <returns>Returns true if we can close current workspace</returns>
private bool closeWorkspace()
{
    Trace.WriteLineIf(TrcLvl.TraceInfo, TrcLvl.TraceInfo ? string.Format("= FormMain.closeWorkspace( {0}: {1} queries )",  
        (this.document.DefaultWorkspace != null ? this.document.DefaultWorkspace.Name : "(null)"), this.MdiChildren.Length) : "");

    this.isClosingWorkspace = true;
    try
    {
        Trace.WriteLineIf(TrcLvl.TraceInfo, TrcLvl.TraceInfo ? string.Format(" - CloseWs: check if some of queries might be busy...") : "");
        foreach (Form mdi in this.MdiChildren)
        {
            if (!(mdi is FormQuery)) continue; // currently only FormQuery can be here, so this check is reserved for future version of app
            FormQuery frmQ = (FormQuery)mdi;
            if (frmQ.CheckIfBusy())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Languages.TranslateFmt("Query[{0}] is busy!", frmQ.Query.Title),
                    Languages.Translate("Fail to Switch Workspace"), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                return false;
            }
        }
        Trace.WriteLineIf(TrcLvl.TraceInfo, TrcLvl.TraceInfo ? string.Format(" - CloseWs: detach queries...") : "");
        List<FormQuery> toClose = new List<FormQuery>();
        foreach (Form mdi in this.MdiChildren)
        {
            if (!(mdi is FormQuery)) continue; 
            FormQuery frmQ = (FormQuery)mdi;
            frmQ.DetachQuery();
            toClose.Add(frmQ);
        }
        Trace.WriteLineIf(TrcLvl.TraceInfo, TrcLvl.TraceInfo ? string.Format(" - CloseWs: closing queries ({0} items)...", toClose.Count) : "");
        for (int i = 0; i < toClose.Count; i++)
        {
            FormQuery frmQ = toClose[i];
            Trace.WriteLineIf(TrcLvl.TraceInfo, TrcLvl.TraceInfo ? string.Format("  - CloseWs#{0}: closing [{1}]...", i, frmQ.Text) : "");
            toClose[i] = null;
            try
            {
                frmQ.Hide();
                //frmQ.Close(); 

                Thread.Sleep(100);
                frmQ.Dispose();
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Trace.WriteLineIf(TrcLvl.TraceError, TrcLvl.TraceError ? string.Format("  !!! CloseWs[#{0}].ERR.{1}\n\t{2}",
                    i, ErrorUtils.FormatErrorMsg(exc), ErrorUtils.FormatStackTrace(exc)) : "");
            }
        }
    }
    finally { this.isClosingWorkspace = false; }
    return true;
}
```

In VS debugger exception pops up here (in FormQuery.Designer.cs):

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    try
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing); // <-- unhandled exception pops up here!
    }
    catch (System.Exception exc) // <-- this DOES NOT WORK AT ALL!
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLineIf(TrcLvl.TraceError, TrcLvl.TraceError ? string.Format("  !!! FormQuery.Designer.ERR.{0}\n\t{1}",
            XService.Utils.ErrorUtils.FormatErrorMsg(exc), XService.Utils.ErrorUtils.FormatStackTrace(exc)) : "");
    }
}
```

As you can see - I tried to put try-catch statement there but .NET is not able to catch it!

Here is a pice from trace log:

```
20200709,104115.32 T1  = FormMain.closeWorkspace( Test 1: 6 queries )
20200709,104115.32 T1   - CloseWs: check if some of queries might be busy...
20200709,104115.32 T1   - CloseWs: detach queries...
20200709,104115.32 T1  Query[#6/Query_2_Errors].ReleaseData()
20200709,104115.32 T1  Query[#7/Query_4_Ini_prm].ReleaseData()
20200709,104115.32 T1  Query[#8/Query_5_func].ReleaseData()
20200709,104115.32 T1  Query[#9/Query_6_app].ReleaseData()
20200709,104115.32 T1  Query[#10/Query_7_OrderInfo].ReleaseData()
20200709,104115.32 T1  Query[#11/Query_8_Bom].ReleaseData()
20200709,104115.32 T1   - CloseWs: closing queries (6 items)...
20200709,104115.32 T1    - CloseWs#0: closing [Query_2_Errors]... <-- here it pops up "unhandled exception" UI
20200709,104131.89 T1  --- FormQuery[Query_4_Ini_prm].Activated()
20200709,104131.89 T1  --- FormQuery[Query_4_Ini_prm].ReportActive()
20200709,104131.89 T1  = FormMain.ReportActive( Query_4_Ini_prm )
20200709,104131.90 T1  = FormMain_MdiChildActivate --- #18 ---
20200709,104132.00 T1    - CloseWs#1: closing [Query_4_Ini_prm]...
20200709,104132.01 T1  --- FormQuery[Query_8_Bom].Activated()
20200709,104132.01 T1  --- FormQuery[Query_8_Bom].ReportActive()
20200709,104132.01 T1  = FormMain.ReportActive( Query_8_Bom )
20200709,104132.02 T1  = FormMain_MdiChildActivate --- #19 ---
20200709,104132.22 T1    - CloseWs#2: closing [Query_5_func]...
```

Here is stack-trace displayed in VS at the moment of exception:

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.Dispose(bool disposing) + 0x19 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(bool disposing) + 0x247 bytes    
> Query.exe!ABC.App.QueryNet.FormQuery.Dispose(bool disposing) Line 22 + 0x13 bytes C#
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose() + 0x19 bytes   
Query.exe!ABC.App.QueryNet.FormMain.closeWorkspace() Line 1230 + 0x15 bytes C#
Query.exe!ABC.App.QueryNet.FormMain.mmiOpenWs_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 1141 + 0xd bytes    C#
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(object key, System.EventArgs e) + 0x5e bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0x53 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0xa2 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.ProcessMnemonic(char charCode) + 0xe bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.ProcessDialogChar(char charCode) + 0x51 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg) + 0x1b1 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(System.Windows.Forms.Control target, ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg) + 0x14e bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.MSG msg) + 0x1f9 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(int dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) + 0x599 bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x578 bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x65 bytes    
Query.exe!ABC.App.QueryNet.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 48 + 0x28 bytes C#
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x47 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x9b bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x4d bytes
```

And the strange thing - there are 6 MDI-child windows in workspace but it reports unhandled exception only for one of MDI childs (always on closing 1st or 2nd MDI child, never on closing other MDI-childs). All the rest of MDI childs are closed fine. I tried to change sequence of MDI childs (by its content) - no way, it is always reporting unhandled exception for 1st or 2nd MDI-child closing despite the content.

I searched internet for this - not found anything. I seen only a ref to possible reason that ActiveX might be used but here that is not the case. My FormQuery is very simple, there are only - Panel, SplitContainer, TextBox, DataGridView, StatusStrip, one ContextMenu - nothig more. So, it does not use any ActiveX components...

I tried to analyze .NET internals with Reflector - I cannot see any possible reasons of such exception.

Also tried to use Hide()+Close(), Hide()+Dispose(), tried to add Thread.Sleep(100) in closeWorkspace() method - no way, it reports exception anyway and it is **completely uncatcable**! :-(

I completely run out of idea - how to figure out why that exception is there?!
Could you please advice - what also I can check to find out the reason of exception and fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to break execution when this NRE is thrown, then examine a call stack

Comment: Thanks for hint. I just added to main question stask-trace which is displayed in VS. As you can see - top stack record is System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.Dispose()+0x19. So, it seems it crash inside ContainerControl destructor (seems parent class of Form)... but why?! I even do not have any guess - how is that possible at all?! Also why +0x19, Reflector shows there is ldnull for unvalidatedControl field...

Comment: Hm... Weird thing - I changed DetachQuery() method to set explicitly ActiveControl = null and now it works fine. So, it looks like Form.Dispose() was crashed because activeControl was not null?!... :-\ But why?!...

Comment: @dmitry_bond can you better descirbe what you did to fix this if you still remember? We have this issue at various points in our code (on forms open, on forms closing, on key events etc) but we're unable to reproduce it reliably.

Answer (score 1):

This is a low-level bug, a fatal combination of MDI, PerformLayout() and the Layout event handler because MDI has to restore a child window from Maximized state before it can bring another child to the front which triggers the form layout engine to re-layout the form running the Layout event handler. This causes a clash of nested code execution as the second form tries to match with the first one. A simple workaround to this bug is to make sure that the active MDI child window is not maximized before closing or display a new one.

```
//Set the active child in normal window state
if (this.ActiveMdiChild != null && this.ActiveMdiChild.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
{
    this.ActiveMdiChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}

foreach (Form mdi in this.MdiChildren)
{
    if (!(mdi is FormQuery)) continue; 
    FormQuery frmQ = (FormQuery)mdi;
    frmQ.DetachQuery();
    toClose.Add(frmQ);
}
```